# Thymeleaf url format for custom url

Tags: thymeleaf

For example I have url like

mychat://com.mychat/

how can I achieve this with thymeleaf syntax?

I tried

But it is invisible in my mail while I send this using thymeleaf

Comment: There is nothing special about those urls.  You can simply treat them as normal and they work (I tested this in Thymeleaf 3).  You're going to have to add more details if you want more help.

Comment: I tried like `<a th:href="@{my chat://com.mychat/}"  th:text="@{my chat://com.mychat/}">Login </a>` but when I send this to mail its not appear as a link it appears as a normal text

Comment: When I use this exact expression: `<a th:href="@{my chat://com.mychat/}" th:text="@{my chat://com.mychat/}">Login </a>` I get an output of `<a href="my chat://com.mychat/">my chat://com.mychat/</a>` in Thymeleaf, which is the expected output.  What gives you the impression that it is wrong?  Have you verified the source of your email (that your email server isn't stripping out those urls?)

Comment: yes it will show `mychat://com.mychat ` but the thing is it doesn't goes as a link [like blue underlined and when we touch it should navigate to the link]. It just shown as a normal text this is my problem.  When I send link using `http` for example `https://www.google.com` it works fine. But when I send link using other things except `http` and `https` it doesn't look as a link